Nuxt development server won't start: esbuild platform mismatch after inactivity
First time I'm encountering this error. I stopped working on my code for like 2 days coming back and trying to run it with the usual npm run dev and I get this error
ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:                                                                                                         11:26:43
You installed esbuild for another platform than the one you're currently using.
This won't work because esbuild is written with native code and needs to
install a platform-specific binary executable.
Ive tried uninstalling and Installing Esbuild but that seemeed to not work

Not sure about the troubleshooting you've done so far, but I recommend: 1. double-checking that you have the same NodeJS version in that project 2. delete node_modules and the cache of your package manager, then reinstall it all again
